# cannot use curl to load docker image from a tarball using docker api

Tags: api, curl, docker, load

My docker version:

```
[cloud-user@firstroot-1 curl]$ sudo docker version

Client:
 Version:      1.10.0
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.3
 Git commit:   590d5108
 Built:        Thu Feb  4 18:34:50 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.10.0
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.3
 Git commit:   590d5108
 Built:        Thu Feb  4 18:34:50 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

I want to load an image from a tarball using curl, but it fails. However I have **no problem** loading it with this command:

```
**sudo docker load --input utuntu.tar**  //works
```

tarball information

```
[cloud-user@firstroot-1 curl]$ pwd
/home/cloud-user/curl
[cloud-user@firstroot-1 curl]$ ls -l utuntu.tar
-rwxrwxrwx 1 cloud-user cloud-user 130499072 Aug  1 15:46 utuntu.tar
```

Here are two curl commands I have tried but failed :

```
sudo ./curl --unix-socket  /var/run/docker.sock  -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-tar" -d "@/home/cloud-user/curl/utuntu.tar"   http:/images/load
Untar re-exec error: exit status 1: output: archive/tar: invalid tar header

sudo ./curl --unix-socket  /var/run/docker.sock  -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-tar" -d "/home/cloud-user/curl/utuntu.tar"   http:/images/load
Untar re-exec error: exit status 1: output: unexpected EOF
```

curl works with commands such as /images/json, /containers/id/start etc, but not load.

The images/load documentation does have much information https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.22/

Comment: seems your tar archive is ok, what is `http:/images/load` ?

Comment: @vitr it's a http uri that only specifies a path, a host isn't required for the socket request

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`--data-binary @<filepath>`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-binary) to "post data exactly as specified with no extra processing whatsoever" from a file.

```
sudo curl --verbose \
 --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock \
 --request POST \
 --header "Content-Type: application/x-tar" \
 --data-binary "@image.tar" \
 http:/images/load
```

[`-d` or `--data`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d) attempts to send the data as it would for submitting a form via the browser.